# How can I run Rails "script/[xyz]" commands on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby

I am used to doing Rails development work on a Mac. However, now other developers will be working with me and they use Windows, both XP and Vista. I am trying to figure out the Windows environment so I can help them.

In OS X and Linux you have this kind of thing...

```
$ cd [Rails project root]
$ script/console
```

Tried it on Windows but all I got was "'script' is not recognized as an internal or external command...etc."

What is the Windows equivalent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get into your rails directory, then type:

```
ruby script/(your command)
```

Make sure that you have the path to ruby on your path - otherwise you need to do:

```
(path to ruby)/ruby script/(your command)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
ruby script/whatever
```

That should do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Does:

```
c:\railsproject\> ruby script/console
```

work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried issuing ruby script\console ? (Windows uses backslashes as path delimeters instead of foreslashes and doesn't support shebang syntax.)

Answer (score 1):

rails path/to/your/new/application

cd path/to/your/new/application

ruby script/server

Check this out: http://rubyonrails.org/download